# Monitor is not picking up my system

Tags: boot, display, hdmi

The title is very vague, but I really didnt know how else to ask my question. I haven't touched my PC for few months because I moved places, lost HDMI cable and hence couldn't connect the monitor to the PC.

Yesterday I finally got a cable and I connected the PC to the monitor. I have Sapphire Radeon RX 480 Nitro 8192MB GDDR5 GPU if it is important. The problem that I have is that altough the computer is turning on, processor fan works and the graphics card is working (both fans are spinning and the Sapphire Logo led lights are on) the monitor doesn't pick up my system.

Yesterday it picked it up once. However it happened very late. I didnt see the usual Bios settings. It only came on on the logging in screen (Windows 10). Pc was working smoothly like always, I switched it off, tried running it again today without any luck.

Monitor and HDMI cable are working like a charm because I connected my laptop to the monitor through this cable, hence it has to be the card or the system. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

As you are sure that your monitor and HDMI cable is working, there is one part left which is your graphics card.

I thought you're confused about the way that electronics devices work. These care complex electrical circuits, which means that a working part does not necessarily represent all the system is functioning.

So, I think it is about your graphics card. You can try another graphics card test the other parts of the system, or it is possible you can take your card out and connect the HDMI directly to the GPU output on the motherboard.

Good luck with that. :)

Comment: Yes Monitor and cable works 100%. I have Gigabyte GA-78-LMT-USB3 MoBo which has an onbord GPU. I disconnected my Gpu, and connected hdmi to the one on the mother board and still there is nothing. Monitor is not picking up anything

Comment: Perhaps you need to explicitly select the discrete graphics in your UEFI settings.